# Having problems with Meteor regex query for Tree structure with materialzed paths

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have tree with materialized paths where I store the path with ids for each node:

```
path: ',tCENL4sLgfTPpNHqA,EDbvc7YD2MpBSz5RR,nh4HhHpdEwkeiXXw2,ENN8hsjnvxi23dp7q,ef4hptkM32ScASa73,i8QdauXtcqjyGCAX7,',
```

When I run the query directly on mongoDb I can find the results:

```
db.tree.find({path:/^,tCENL4sLgfTPpNHqA,/}).count();
```

But when I run the query through Meteor to get all the subtree for the root I do not get any results. I have run the following two queries with no results.

```
var rootPath = "/^," + rootNode._id + ",/";

Tree.find({path:rootPath}).fetch();
```

**UPDATE**
The problem is with generating the rootpath variable in separate chunks as string. If I replace the rootPath with a hardcoded id, it works.

So my question now is how to construct a regex on the fly with a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use variables in regex query building, use like this:

```
Tree.find({path:new RegExp(rootNode._id)}).fetch();
```